# Passing BOOST_PP_DEC to another macro

Tags: c, macros, boost-preprocessor

I'm trying to accomplish something like:

```
#define FOO( N ) Bar ## N ## _ Bar ## N - 1
```

So say `FOO( 2 ) = Bar2_Bar1`

The problem lies in the `N-1` there.  Pre-processors won't do math like this, but boost has the handy BOOST_PP_DEC macro to decrement the input.

So if I now try the following:

```
#define __FOO( N, N_MINUS_ONE ) BAR ## N _ ## Bar ## N_MINUS_ONE
#define FOO( N ) __FOO( N, BOOST_PP_DEC( N ) )
```

I would have expected that to work, but it actually pastes the macro name directly and doesn't evaluate it.

Oddly though, if I just do:

```
#define TEST( N ) BOOST_PP_DEC( N )
```

It seems to work.  What am I missing here exactly?

Comment: Actually after some more playing around it looks like passiong it through an intermediate macro fixes it up so

    #define FOO( N ) _FOO( N, BOOST_PP_DEC( N ) )
    #define _FOO( N, N2 ) __FOO( N, N2 )
    #define __FOO( N, N2 ) ...

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use double leading underscores for any names, or single leading underscore for global names, and that includes pre-processor macros. Those names are reserved by the C specification for internal compiler/c-library names.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define FOO( N ) BOOST_PP_CAT(Bar ## N ## _Bar, BOOST_PP_DEC(N))
```